# Garbage collection of object after exception

Tags: python, exception, destructor

I have observed that after an exception I have an object for which constructor is not called, which causes a lock to be held. What is the best way to improve the situation? Would calling del in an except block be the solution?

```
b=BigHash(DB_DIR, url)
meta = bdecode(b.get())
return meta
```

b holds a lock which is released on destruction (it's a C++ object)
an exception is thrown by b.get().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this to make sure b in unlocked

```
b=BigHash(DB_DIR, url)
try:
    meta = bdecode(b.get())
    return meta
finally:
    #unlock b here
```

A cleaner way would be if BigHash can work as a context, so you can write

```
with b as BigHash(DB_DIR, url):
    meta = bdecode(b.get())
    return meta
```

You might have to add some code to BigHash to make it work as a context though

Comment: Can't I use "with" or other language trick? From a C++ I find problematic that an object that falls out of scope isn't destructed.

Comment: @plotr, the object is destructed when it goes out of scope, but maybe it has modified the locked status of BigHash. Can you show the source for BigHash?

Comment: It's a couple of hundred lines of C++, so that would be impractical. The important thin is that the bucket is locked on constructor and unlocked on destructor. And python's GC seems to leave the object lying around.

Comment: You would not use `except` in this instance, you would use `finally`. You would not use a bare `except` (without a bare `raise`) in *any* instance.

Comment: @piotr, the size of the existing code doesn't matter, you'd just need to add `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to make it work with `with`. Another way would be to wrap the class with a lock manager.

Answer (score 3):

No matter what, you want the lock to be released - whether or not an exception is thrown. In that case, it's probably best to release the lock/delete b in a `finally:` clause:

```
b=BigHash(DB_DIR, url)
try:
    meta = bdecode(b.get())
finally:
    del b # or whatever you need to do to release the lock
return meta
```

You could also use a context manager - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager. Simply add code to free the lock in the `BigHash.__exit__` function, which will be called after leaving the `with` block in the following code:

```
with BigHash(DB_DIR, url) as b:
    meta = bdecode(b.get())
return meta
```

Comment: Surprisingly in python 2.5.4 this isn't working with "with".
The destructor is not being called.

Comment: @piotr: Your BigHash class must have the `__exit__` method defined to play well with `with`.  See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers

Answer (score 0):

Calling `del` on a name is something you prettymuch never should do. **Calling `del` does not guarantee anything useful about what will happen to the underlying object.** You should never depend on a `__del__` method for something you need to happen.

`del` only gets rid of one reference to an object, which can be confusing when you may have made more without thinking. Therefore, `del` is useful for cleaning up a namespace, not for controlling the lifetime of objects, and *it's not even great for that*—the proper way to control a name's lifetime is to put it in a function and have it go out of scope or put it in a with block.

You need to equip `BigHash` with the ability to release the lock *explicitly*, with an `release` or `unlock` or `close` method. If you want to use this with a context manager (`with`), you can define `__exit__`, which will get called at a predictable, useful time.